# c# singleton winform load/unload images

Tags: c#, image, singleton, dispose, idisposable

I have a winform application. The main form is singleton and it loads a lot of images. The images represents products, and every time I click on a image, I modify the stock of the product and reload the hashtable of products and the images.

The issue is with every time I reload the hashtable of products from BBDD and reloads the images. At the end of the day, the application drains a lot of memory and I don't know when and how to unload the images in order to reload (because some times I can modify the image and I have to reload too)

The code that reloads the hashtable and the buttons is:

```
Family fam = new Family();

List<Family> listFamilies = fam.loadFamilies();
htProducts.Clear();

foreach(Family family in listFamilies)
{
   //reload all the products of each family
   if(htProducts[family.idFamily]==null)
   {
     List<Product> listProducts= fam.loadProductsFamily(family.idFamily);
     htProducts[family.idFamily] = listProducts;
   }
   Button bt = new Button();
   bt.location = new Point(x,y); //The buttons are created dinamically
   bt.Parent = panelFamilies;//I have all the buttons inside a panel.
   try
   {
      if(family.urlImage !="")
      {
         bt.Text=family.Name;
         bt.Image = new Bitmap(family.urlImage);
      }
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     ....
    }

}
```

When I click on a Family button it loads the products of that family but the code is more or less the same. And it loads images too.

More ore less this is the code. The problem is that everyTime I click on a button, I load more buttons with the products and loads images.

A lot of times I reload the singleton form and executes the previous code, and load the images again and drains the memory.

¿When and how I have to unload the images?

EDIT:

I've added the following code before loading again the buttons with the images:

```
foreach (Control c in panel8.Controls)
{
    if (c is Button)
        c.Dispose();
}
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);// I think that isn't correct to use because I've read,  but reduces the memory.
```

It will dispose all the buttons and images of the panel and reduce the memory before load the images again?

btw sorry for my english :(

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well how about showing some code.. we are not mind readers her..

Comment: You really need to go into more depth about what you're trying to do. Explaining what you've looked into so far & providing some code would go a long way.

Comment: yes sorry, I've updated the explanation with some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (Control c in panel8.Controls)
{
    if (c is Button)
        c.Dispose();
}
```

That cannot work.  In general, .NET collection classes raise an InvalidOperationException when you alter the collection in a foreach statement that iterates the collection.  Unfortunately, that's not implemented for the Controls collection.  So what this code does is only dispose every other control.  Which is enough to cause an uncontrolled resource leak, not just the Button controls but also their images.

The fix is to iterate the Controls collection backwards, like this:

```
for (int ix = panel8.Controls.Count - 1; ix >= 0; --ix) {
    Control c = panel8.Controls[ix];
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: ok, more or less the same if you want to delete some valuepair of a dictionary. I will try your option. Anyway, your option is valid to unload the loaded images? I have to call to GC.Collect? Because I've read that isn't correct to call because it executes automatically.

Comment: Properly disposing the buttons will now also dispose their Image property.  Don't use GC.Collect().

Comment: ok thanks. I used because executing the app with the gc.collect(GC.MaxGeneration) I can see how memory reduces, anyway I will try without it.

Comment: one more think, in your "for" code, Can I write there: c.Dispose(); and it will free memory when GC.collect() executes automatically? It will erase all the images in memory? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're holding onto a reference or two in your form.

You should take a look at your process using a debugger like CLRProfiler or ANTs to understand what's taking up so much memory in your process. Once you have this information you can take the next step of making sure you're freeing all references to it so it can be collected.

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot, call

```
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);
```

This will force garbage collection. Then in process explorer or task manager check the memory usage. If its smaller, it only means that the runtime decided not to collect the memory.

If it didn't work, you need to find the memory leak.

Comment: I've read that it's bad to call GC. Anyway my winform is singleton because I need it, but I need to reload the images again because sometimes the image's url of some buttons can change. But every time I reload all the buttons with the images the memory grows...

Comment: Yes, one should not use GC, but I wrote that you can do it when troubleshooting. Then remove the GC calls.